# Access has been blocked by CORS issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to access the laravel server from vue.js end. But it shows

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/registerDoctor' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I set every possible thing to solve it. It worked fine before I modified it. when I click on `http://localhost:8000/api/registerDoctor` it shows `GET` method is not allowed here, `POST` method is allowed.

**CORS Code**

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domain = ['http://localhost:8080'];
        if(isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
            $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
            if(in_array($origin, $domain)){
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
        // return $next($request);
        return redirect('/home');
    }

`
```

what to do?

Comment: check the ports `8000` != `8080`

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

Use this package and it will make your code work fine
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: The problem occurs in case of registration of a user. But other communications between user end and server end is perfectly done. Like add a department, add a schedule and other CRUD operations are okay